# How to incorporate prior information in pomegranate? In other words: Does pomegranate support incremental learning?

Tags: python, pomegranate

Say I fit a model using `pomegranate` to the data available at that time.  Once more data is coming in, I'd like to update the model accordingly.  In order words, is it possible with `pomegranate` to update the existing model with new data without overriding the previous parameter? Just to be clear: I'm not referring to out-of-core learning, since my question relates to data being available at different time points rather than having too-large-for-memory data available at a single time point.

Here is what I tried:

```
>>> from pomegranate.distributions import BetaDistribution

>>> # suppose a coin generated the following data, where 1 is head and 0 is tail
>>> data1 = [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]

>>> # as usual, we fit a Beta distribution to infer the bias of the coin
>>> model = BetaDistribution(1, 1)
>>> model.summarize(data1)  # compute sufficient statistics

>>> # presume we have seen all the data available so far,
>>> # we can now estimate the parameters
>>> model.from_summaries()

>>> # this results in the following model (so far so good)
>>> model
{
    "class" :"Distribution",
    "name" :"BetaDistribution",
    "parameters" :[
        3.0,
        7.0
    ],
    "frozen" :false
}

>>> # now suppose the coin is flipped a few more times, getting the following data
>>> data2 = [0, 1, 0, 0, 1]

>>> # we would like to update the model parameters accordingly
>>> model.summarize(data2)

>>> # but this fits only data2, overriding the previous parameters
>>> model.from_summaries()
>>> model
{
    "class" :"Distribution",
    "name" :"BetaDistribution",
    "parameters" :[
        2.0,
        3.0
    ],
    "frozen" :false
}


>>> # however I want to get the result that corresponds to the following,
>>> # but ideally without having to "drag along" data1
>>> data3 = data1 + data2
>>> model.fit(data3)
>>> model  # this should be the final model
{
    "class" :"Distribution",
    "name" :"BetaDistribution",
    "parameters" :[
        5.0,
        10.0
    ],
    "frozen" :false
}
```

**Edit**:

Another way to ask the question: Does `pomegranate` support *incremental* or *online learning*?  Basically, I'm looking for something similar to `scikit-learn`'s `partial_fit()` as you can find [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.BernoulliNB.html#sklearn.naive_bayes.BernoulliNB.partial_fit).

Given that `pomegranate` supports [out-of-core learning](https://github.com/jmschrei/pomegranate/blob/master/tutorials/C_Feature_Tutorial_2_Out_Of_Core_Learning.ipynb), I feel like I'm overlooking something.  Any help?

Answer (score 0):

It is actually `from_summaries` that is the issue. In the case of the Beta distribution it does: `self.summaries = [0, 0]`. All of the `from_summaries` methods are destructive. They replace the summaries with the parameters in the distribution. The summaries can always be updated for additional observations, the parameters can not be.

I think this is a bad design. It would be better to treat them as accumulators of observations with the parameters as derived cached values.

If you do:

```
model = BetaDistribution(1, 1)
model.summarize(data1)
model.summarize(data2)
model.from_summaries()
model
```

You will find that it does produce the same result as if `model.summarize(data1 + data2)` had been used.

Comment: Thank you @dan-d! So, you are saying that, as of now, `pomegranate` does not support incremental learning, correct?  I would need to "drag along" all data and refit the model entirely new on the data that is available at that time.

Comment: It is that it has a bad design where `from_summaries` clears the summaries when it computes the parameters. It should be only an explicit call to `clear_summaries` that does that. Fixing that would only require deleting some lines from the end of every `from_summaries` method.